# Change browser time to test return value of Date()?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to change the browser's time without manipulating the system clock?

Comment: The short answer is no. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: So the Date() function returns a date different from my timezone.

Comment: @A00: you might want to rephrase your question (or ask a different one), then, as that's a completely different problem.

Comment: I want to do this so that I can do e2e testing with cypress and assert that the system behaves differently at different times.

Answer (score 49):

The browser doesn't really "have time", it gets its time from the system clock. Of course, if you want to do something particularly nasty, you could override the Date functions.

```
Date.prototype.getTime = function() { return 1 };
(new Date).getTime(); // 1
```

So if you wanted to set the time to 1am November 4th 1989, you'd first find the time value:

```
(new Date('1989-11-04T01:00:00')).getTime() // Returns 626144400000
```

Then mock it in browser:

```
Date.prototype.getTime = function() { return 626144400000 };
```

Comment: I've tested it and it works, thanks for this awesome trick. But I have questions,
Let's use a dummy website (https://www.timeanddate.com/timer/)
Set a timer (say for 5 mins)
Now,
1. After setting the time to a future point, we can skip time in the timer as well but why the timer is moving forward after that? Haven't I just broken the function by telling it to give the fixed time?
2. If I set the time to a past point than now, the timer stops working, why is that.

Answer (score 22):

No. The browser doesn't have a time. The system does.

Answer (score 8):

You can run the browser in a virtual machine (VMWare/VirtualPC/etc.) and change the time of the OS in the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [timemachine](https://github.com/schickling/timemachine) to override system's time before each test and resetting it after each test.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for in browser solution for mocking and moving clock forward then this is something i came up with:

```
var mockedNow = (new Date('2023-12-29T18:00:00')).getTime();
setInterval(function(){mockedNow+=1000}, 1000);
Date.now = function() { return  mockedNow};
```

Set `mockedNow` to desired date time. `setInterval` will be increasing  it by one second like normal clock would.