# Change the browser's Date/time value using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to change the value returned from javascript's `new Date()` function.
In general - I'm looking for a way to write an extension that will give the user the ability to set his timezone (or diff from the time of his system's clock) without changing time/timezone on his computer.

I checked the [chrome extension api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) but found nothing there. Will appreciate it if someone can point me at the right direction.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: @Dekel did you finish this extension? Can I get it in the Chrome WebStore? It would be nice for debugging :)

Comment: The [Timeshift extension](https://mybrowseraddon.com/change-timezone.html) lets you set the desired timezone.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen some solutions involving overriding javascript's `getTime()` method:

```
Date.prototype.getTime = function() { return [DATE + OFFSET] };
```

usage:

```
(new Date).getTime();
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976992/4926817))

Apparently the time does not come from the browser but rather the operating system. So my suggestion would be to inject this javascript using a content script, and in your overriding function, you can offset the date/time by however much you would like.

Comment: That's basically how the [Timeshift extension](https://mybrowseraddon.com/change-timezone.html) does it, if you look at its source code (in `data/content_script/inject.js`). It redefines all properties of `Date`, e.g. `Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toJSON', {"value": function () {return toJSON.call(this._date)}});`.